# C++ running grep in execv searches for executable path

Tags: c++, linux, bash, exec, fork

```
argv = {'/usr/bin/grep', '/usr/bin/grep', '-ri', 'test', '.', 0}    

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {

execv(argv[0], argv);

exit(0);
}
else {
  wait(NULL);
}
```

This is what I have for my code. I am simply trying to get the grep command to run. The problem I run into is that it thinks the second /usr/bin/grep is the search pattern.

I have tried to change the argv array to only contain one /usr/bin/grep, but that errors out and does not run the grep. Any help?

Comment: That code doesn't compile, at all.

Comment: You might want to read about [`execv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execv` takes the command as the first parameter so you want `"usr/bin/grep"` not `argv[0]` which is the program you are running. Also remove the first parameter from `argv`.

I would also check that `grep` is in `/usr/bin`  it's often in `/bin`.